# For H-1B visas, what are job codes, what are they for and how are they chosen?

Tags: working-visas, h1-visa

I want to understand what job codes are for (while applying for H-1B visa).

How does the immigration lawyer decide which job code to put on there?

Is there a minimum and maximum salary associated with each of these job codes?

Also it will be super helpful if someone can share a list of these job codes. I want in particular to find out for roles for folks with a CS background and EEE background (specifically semiconductors).

Initial research. - Most of my friends come from a Masters background. Few of my friends who have come here on L1 and then transitioned to H1 they have had to apply under a "job code". The company with which they are applying usually decides the job code and the person does not have much transparency in this regard.

To understand this process better I want to know the relevance of these job codes. These are some of the job codes I found by Googling
http://www.immihelp.com/visas/h1b/lca-occupation-codes.html

I wanted understand a further breakdown of these categories.

Comment: Can you clarify your specific question? Is it simply what the job codes are?